# Type of irrational number in $R$

Tags: real-analysis

How can we prove that all irrational numbers in real line can not be represented as union of countable closed sets.

The result intuitively makes sense and we all know the irrational numbers are uncountable and dense on $R$. And I don't know how to use these facts to prove the result in strict math language.

Comment: Union of countable closed sets? Or union of countably many closed sets?

Comment: Union of countably many closed sets